# How to display data from ArrayList hourly?

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I want to show data in this format,

**12-22-2011 11:00:00**

```
[12-22-2011 11:13:39] Warning: Contact 'nagiosadmin' service notification command '/usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: PROBLEM\n\nService: C:\ Drive Space\nHost: m-hussain.Musewerx2\nAddress: 192.168.1.106\nState: WARNING\n\nDate/Time: Thu Dec 22 11:13:08 EST 2011\n\nAdditional Info:\n\ncould not fetch information from server\n" | /bin/mail -s "** PROBLEM Service Alert: m-hussain.Musewerx2/C:\ Drive Space is WARNING **" mohsin.raza@musewerx.com' timed out after 30 seconds

[12-22-2011 11:13:08] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;m-hussain.Musewerx2;C:\ Drive Space;WARNING;notify-service-by-email;could not fetch information from server
```

**12-22-2011 10:00:00**

```
[12-22-2011 10:02:19] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;arsalan.hussain;C:\ Drive Space;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;c:\ - total: 19.53 Gb - used: 19.17 Gb (98%) - free 0.36 Gb (2%)

[12-22-2011 10:00:29] Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.
```

my Array list such that each line of the above data is at unique index of array list how to campare data to show it hour wise,

```
ArrayList eventLog = new ArrayList();
```

Such that i have all data in array list i want to show data in this format how wouls i show data hourly wise in JSP

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are asking. We understand that English may not be your first language, but if you can make this question more clear, it will help us help you!

Comment: i want to display data as i have mentioned above and the data which i want to show is in array list so what can i do with that data in array list to show data as i want

Comment: Not quite related to the question, but PLEASE use a different date format.  When it's one of the first 12 days of the month, it's impossible to know whether the date is dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy.  If you're going to use hyphens as the separator, please give some thought to using the slightly more standard yyyy-mm-dd form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list is sorted you can do something like this (pure Java, translate to what you sue in your JSP)

```
String header = null;
List<String> lines = getLines();
for (String line: lines) {
    String currentTime = line.substring(1, 14);
    if (!currentTime.equals(header)) {
        header = currentTime;
        System.out.format("%0$s:00:00\n", header);
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Starting with no header we iterate over all lines. The date and house are extracted from the current line. If they differ from the current header, then the header is changed to the current date and hour and printed. Then the line is printed.

If there are large gaps among the time stamps then no headers will be printed of those gaps.

Comment: you are using list ? and the data i have is in array list ?so shoule i place my array list in your list place?

Comment: @SalmanRaza Yes you should have your ArrayList instead, I used a List to show how it should work. A plain array of String would also work.

Comment: @Roger it is printing the data as it was printing before i just comment "system.format" line because it was giving me error as i have use it at jsp page and one more thing where it is printing "header" ??  it is simply printing line after checking date??

Comment: @SalmanRaza I had missed the header in the format. Have updated the code. Of course you could instead use System.out.println(header + ":00:00") or similar. (Note to self, run code before posting!)

Comment: @Roger i am just getting error "; expected" at this format line

Comment: @Roger i remove that error now error is invalid character constant

Comment: @ROger thanks for your help i am using out.format("%0$s:00:00\n",header); in jsp for formatting i think JSP is not getting "%0$s:00:00\n" and resulting in error "Invalid Character Constant"

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a `List<String>` or `List<YourOwnClass>` and you want to sort them based on the time and display.

Use `java.util.Comparator` to compare two entires.
In the case of `List<String>` it would be

```
class StringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

       public int compare(String e1, String e2) {
           return e1.substring(0,12).compareTo(e2.substring(0,12));//[12-22-2011 10:02:19]
       }
   }
}
```

In the case of YourOwnObject compare the appropriate field.

Then call `Collections.sort(list, new StringComparator());`

Remember this is in place sort. So if you dont want to modify the list, then take a copy of that before you sort.